# F5 in Chrome does not refresh css anymore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use chrome since beginning. Always it was possible for me to use f5 or browser refresh to load all files new (status code 200). Since this saturday I have to open the developer tools to make this work or I have to press ctrl + f5. How can I force with "just" f5 to download all the files new?

thank you

Comment: I always use ctrl + r

Comment: works also but before f5 was just enough. I press this thousand of times a day

Comment: It was changed in https://crbug.com/558829 for all platforms (committed in May so it should have been in Stable during summer, apparently in v52).

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you. Yes apparently. Rolled out this saturday. It was very comfortable to use just f5. Well, I have found a solution in my post at the bottom. This works well and I dont get automated updates anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a hard refresh. Do this by Ctrl and F5. That should work

Comment: Or you could get rid of your cookies etc to stop the browser from displaying old data

Comment: Like I said, I know this all. CTRL and F5 is working but before F5 was enough.

Comment: Like I said, the browser is storing the information from memory so F5 isnt going to work on its own now. You need to empty it and then it will work again

Comment: This is not true. I installed a older browser version from http://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php 2016-09-19 - 53.0.2785.116 - with this version, you can use just f5.